# R: add x rows with value y

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have a dataframe (`df1`) with three columns: `Name`, `Decade` and `Count`. For example:

```
Name <- c("a","b","c")
Decade <- c(1810,1850,1900)
Count <- c(2,3,1)
df1 <- data.frame(Name,Decade,Count)
print(df1)
  Name Decade Count
1    a   1810     2
2    b   1850     3
3    c   1900     1
```

I wish to create a new dataframe (`df2`) with columns `Name` and `Decade`, with repeating rows of values in `df1$Name` and `df1$Decade` by `df1$Count`. For each repeating row in df2, I wish the `df2$Decade` to increase by an increment of 10. The first instance of each `df2$Name` and `df2$Decade` combination would be equal to `df1$Name` and `df1$Decade`.

In the above example, my desired output would be:

```
> print(df2)
  Name Decade
1    a   1810
2    a   1820
3    b   1850
4    b   1860
5    b   1870
6    c   1900
```

I would love to show my workings so far, but I don't know how to start and have been manually doing it in excel. [hangs head in shame]

Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using a combination of `tidyverse` and `splitstackshape`. After duplicating rows according to `Count`, we can use `row_number` minus 1 to create a sequence for each group (e.g., 0, 1, 2...), then multiply by 10 to get the 10 year increment and add to the `Decade` for that group.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(splitstackshape)

df2 <- expandRows(df1, "Count") %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(Decade = Decade + (row_number()-1) *10)
```

Or if you don't want to load another package, we could create the duplicated rows with base R:

```
df2 <- df1[rep(seq(nrow(df1)), df1$Count),c(1:2)] %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(Decade = Decade + (row_number()-1) *10)
```

**Output**

```
df2

  Name  Decade
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 a       1810
2 a       1820
3 b       1850
4 b       1860
5 b       1870
6 c       1900
```

Answer (score 2):

Sequences should sort this very quickly:

```
df2 <- df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1$Count), 1:2]
df2$Decade <- df2$Decade + (sequence(df1$Count)-1) * 10
df2

#    Name Decade
#1      a   1810
#1.1    a   1820
#2      b   1850
#2.1    b   1860
#2.2    b   1870
#3      c   1900
```

Comment: This also did the job. Thank you for your time!